# Nextcloud: Unstable SMB Connection

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, owncloud, smb-conf, nextcloud

I am using Nextcloud on UBUNTU Server 16.04 LTS, and I tried to add an external smb storage (a Windows Network Drive). I activated the external storage app on Nextcloud, installed php-libsmbclient and smbclient on my LINUX server and entered the following settings on my Admin External Storage menue:

- Users cannot mount external storage (since I am admin).
- Added an SMB/CIFS Storage to the System, available for myself
- Authentication: Username and Password
- Host: IP-Address of the SMB-Server
- Share: MyShare
- Subfolder: MySubFolder
- Domain: MyDomain
- User: My(Windows/smb)Username
- Password: My(Windows/SMB)Password

The connection works for a couple of seconds, then it breaks.

When I browse the content of the SMB-Storage, after a couple of seconds I get the following Error "Storage is temporarily unavailable".

In the Admin Panel for external storage, there is a test icon at the left of the config. When I enter the config, it is green. But after a couple of seconds, it turns red. If I keep trying, it gets back green, and then red, etc...

I have the impression that the connection works, but it is unstable.

The browser shows me the right information about the last file edits in my external storage.

Am I missing something in the server configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by just reinstalling samba and cifs-utils , then restarting the server.